# What Nvidia driver should i be using?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a nvidia geforce 840m with intel hd graphics and an intel i7 4th generation, its an asus laptop k550l. I am wondering if i can use the nvidia optimus technology with bumblebee even if it is not specified with a stick or anything on my laptop, I know it increases battery life and that is my main problem so far. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to

**System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers**

[image]

Choose your preferred drivers.

With Bumblebee if you want to run an application using dedicated graphics use:

```
    optirun <AppName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Up until 2013, nVidia didn't have any plans to support optimus technology in Linux. That's the reason [project Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) had started. But in May 2013, nVidia started providing partial support for optimus tech on Linux and it has been quite some time.

But Bumblebee has evolved a lot and is officially supported by Ubuntu since Ubuntu 13.10. You can head over to the [wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and install the bumblebee drivers and try them out. It is quite battery efficient and is also [suggested by steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/5/846939854395048434/) for running steam games on linux. And if it doesn't suit your needs, you can definitely fall back to the proprietary nVidia drivers and install them from `System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers`